what's difference in triggerOpenMergeRequestOnPush's values, both, source and never?
I'm new to Jenkins, and after some investigation, still can not find the answer about the triggerOpenMergeRequestOnPush setting in jenkins script.
The docs from gitlab annotation showed
"
If enabled, then the build will be triggered when changes are made to open merge requests in the GitLab repository."
But what's difference in 'both' and 'source' ?
I have tried google and search source code in github.

source: The build is likely triggered when changes are made to the source branch of the open merge request.
both: The build is probably triggered when changes are made to either the source branch or the target branch of the open merge request.
never: The build is not triggered by changes to open merge requests.
from
https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dabsquared/gitlabjenkins/GitLabPushTrigger.java#L699
